# jQuery blur-event not fired on hidden element

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, onblur

I'm simply trying to bind the `blur` event to a set of `inputs` found on my page.

```
var $urlTextBoxes = $(`input[type='url'][data-url-prefixer]`);
$urlTextBoxes.on("blur", onUrlTextBoxBlur);
```

whereas `onUrlTextBoxBlur` is a simple `function` checking the current value,

If the `<input type="url" data-url-prefixer />` is already visible when prefixing with 'http://' if not already set.`$(function () { // ... }` is called, the `onUrlTextBoxBlur` is called on `blur`.

On the other hand, if the `input` is hidden on load (inside a div) and shown later, the `onUrlTextBoxBlur` is never hit and I don't get the point why?

I've tried

```
$(document).on("blur", $urlTextBoxes, onUrlTextBoxBlur);
```

which is not working at all.

Putting

```
if (jQuery._data($("#ExternalRegistrationUrl")[0] !== undefined)) {
    console.log($("#ExternalRegistrationUrl")[0]);
    console.log(jQuery._data($("#ExternalRegistrationUrl")[0], "events"));
}
```

shows

```
input#ExternalRegistrationUrl.form-control
Object {blur: Array[1]}
```

in master, and

```
input#ExternalRegistrationUrl.form-control
undefined
```

in my sub-view. Somehow, the event gots lost. But, how can this be? The `Masters` onReady is called before the `SubViews` onReady, or not?

Seems like another plugin is removing the content and re-adding it afterwards. Therefore, all `bindings` are lost. Now I need a way to re-bind by events after the plugin has done it's magic!

Comment: Do you have a click handler on the element or on a parent? Can you provide a demo?

Comment: At which point are you binding blur event?

Comment: @NemanjaTodorovic: At my masters `$(function () { // ... }`. (It's an MVC4 project). I need it on each page in my project.

Answer (score 1):

HIDDEN FIELD ALSO WORKING WITH BLUR

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/hemal_301080/yapu8k52/2/)**

**SCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(":text").hide();
  $(":text").blur(function(){
    alert("Blurred");

  });;
  $(":text").show();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" />
```

**CSS**

```
input
{
  display:none
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to check when an element loses a binding? I've got a feeling, that some other part is removing the `event-binding` after it has been set

Comment: You can find it with `$(':text:not(.bound)').length;`

Comment: This will give you textboxes which are not bound to any event.

Comment: This shows me 2 on a page where are indeed 2 textboxes, but the `callback` is hit. On the other page it shows 1, but it's not working for this single `<input>`. I'm using `console.log(this.$urlTextBoxes.not(".bound").length);`

Comment: No, sorry. In chrome dev-tools I can see, that there is no `EventListener` for the faulting `input` attached. Question: How can I find out (set a breakpoint), when the event gets unbound?